# Swift creating a function that runs another function that was implemented while called.(Not that complex)

Tags: swift, function

Hello i am trying to create a kickass function to show alerts and run it's function. Buuut unfortunately Xcode and i am getting confused in here:

```
buttonAction:Array<(Any) -> Any)>
```

**Expected '>' to complete generic argument list**

```
func callAlert(_ view: UIViewController, title:String, message:String, buttonName:Array<String>, buttonAction:Array<(Any) -> Any)>) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    for index in 0..<buttonName.count{
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonName[index], style: .default, handler: { action in
    switch action.style{
    case .default:
        print("default")
        buttonAction()

    case .cancel:
        print("cancel")

    case .destructive:
            print("destructive")

        }}))}
    view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How do i call function? Please check below:

```
callAlert(self,
          title: "Donate type",
          message: "Thanks for your support!",
          buttonName: ["Buy me a coffee!","Something"]
    )
```

Comment: Get rid if the extra `)` and then you can move on to the next of several errors you have.

Comment: Is there a way to put funcA() and funcB() in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all I highly recommend to implement the method as an **extension** of `UIViewController`.
- Second of all I'd prefer `presentAlert()` over `callAlert()`
- Third of all rather than two arrays for buttons and actions use **one** array of tuples for `title`, `style` and `action`.
  By the way unspecified type `(Any) -> Any` is very, very bad because `UIAlertAction` handlers are clearly `((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?`
- Finally add an optional `completion` handler

---

```
extension UIViewController {

    func presentAlert(title: String,
                      message: String,
                      alertActions: [(title: String, style: UIAlertAction.Style, action: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?)],
                      completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        for action in alertActions {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action.title, style: action.style, handler: action.action))
        }
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

And use it inside an `UIViewController`

```
let buyCoffeeAction : (UIAlertAction) -> Void = { action in
    // do something
}

let somethingAction : (UIAlertAction) -> Void = { action in
    // do something
}

presentAlert(title: "Donate type",
             message: "Thanks for your support!",
             alertActions: [(title: "Buy me a coffee!", style: .default, action: buyCoffeeAction),
                            (title: "Something", style: .destructive, action: somethingAction)],
             completion: nil)
```

Comment: @KaanKaray so you think the difference between writing a closure and a fucntion will make sense , if so How ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I didn't wanted to use extra functions to fix how many alert buttons can be added, the way he shows made more sense for some reason i guess. I am not using how he made too actually made it easier for myself,         
`alertActions: [(title: "Buy me a coffee!", style: .default, action: { action in self.loadProducts(donateCoffee)}),`   Thanks for your input too btw! :)

Comment: BTW still not convinced but ok ok